# Error while running mongo server

Tags: mongodb

I am totally a beginner with mac , I get this error while trying to open the server using mongod 
10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminatin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have [journalling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling) enabled? If not, and your mongod instance crashed, then you may need to perform a recovery. In this case, what you should do is

1. start mongod with the repair switch: `mongod --repair`. It will run, and then terminate having deleted the lock file.
2. start mongod again normally.

Once you do this, I highly recommend that you enable journalling by using the `--journal` command line switch when you start mongod.

Answer (score 14):

The error usually indicates that the lock file is still present from a previous run.  That means that the mongod process is stil running, check:

```
ps auxwww | grep mongod
```

If it is not listed, then remove the lock file and start mongod again.  If it is listed and unresponsive you may have to kill the process (assuming you cannot connect).  Try a regular kill before a kill -9 etc.

If the process is not there, or you kill it successfully, remove the lock file and restart mongod - if you had journaling enabled everything should be fine.  If not, you may need the repair operation suggested by Sean.

Comment: its listed but am not sure how to kill it. please help

Comment: try the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-kill

Answer (score 6):

Run `sudo mongod`because you need to have admin access. From there, you just need to type in a password.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember way back when, you need to `sudo mkdir /data`: I believe that MongoDB will assume that the base directory that it needs exists and won't create it on its own.

Comment: I don't get your answer, but I installed mongo 3 months ago and I was working with it till yesterday!

Comment: @Dalia If this is the case, it might be that your mongodb has crashed or not done a clean shutdown for some other reason. Remove the lock file and do a repair on the database, and hopefully everything works again.